# Solving $\cos2x-2\sin x-\cos^2x=-3$ with identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to solve
$$\cos2x-2\sin x-\cos^2x=-3$$
I'm trying to find possible solutions in the interval $[0,2\pi]$, but I need to simplify the equation using trig identities first. I just can't seem to find the right ones to use.

Comment: Hint: First, $\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$. Thus, the expression is equivalent to $\sin^2x+2\sin x=3$. Use $k=\sin x$, thus, do you have to solve the equation $k^2+2k-3=0$. Try do it from here!

Comment: Well, for starters, you could use $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2x-1$.

Comment: Even better, what @DiegoMath said.

Comment: You don't need trig identities to solve this. Try plotting the function $\,\cos2x-2\sin x-\cos^2x\,$ on $\,[0,2\pi]\,$ to get a rough idea of where it equals $\,-3.\,$ If the value of $\,x\,$ is near a rational multiple of $\,\pi\,$ then verify that that is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos2x-2\sin x-\cos^2x=-3$$
Substitute $\cos 2x =\cos^2x-\sin^2 x$

$$\cos^2x-\sin^2 x-2\sin x-\cos^2x=-3\to \sin^2x+2\sin x-3=0$$
$$\sin x=1;\;\sin x=-3$$
$$\sin x=1\to x=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
The second result is discarded because $|\sin x|\le 1$ so $\sin x =-3$ is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Generally with these types of questions, a good method is to transform your equation into an equation in terms of only one variable, such as only in terms of $\sin x$ or $\cos x$.

To do this, the following formulae sould be useful:
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x\equiv1$$
$$\cos2x\equiv\cos^2x-\sin^2x\equiv2\cos^2x-1\equiv1-2\sin^2x$$
I leave it to you to choose which ones to use.

If you need any more help, please don't hesitate to ask :)